# 3 UIWebView on UIScrollview crashes when leaf through

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uikit

I've got 3 `UIWebView` on `UIScrollView`. User can scroll these webviews from left to right and back (5-15 pages).
When user scroll one page I move webviews and load new content to invisible one. I'm not remove/release webviews, just change frames and content.
Some pages have cached and I'm using

```
[self loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: url];
```

for loading these pages.

It works fine but: if I'm scrolling fast - then I have crashed app with next message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'

If I comment **loadHTMLString** line then app works fine...

Why it does happen? How to fix it?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You 're receiving memory warning call. And some retained object you're using are just freed. 
Check into ur [viewDidLoad] / [viewDidUnload] methods to check when your data are freed and then reused again.

By the way webViews are using huge amount of ram

Comment: Ok, i have read too fast your question. the CALayer you 're using (your scroll objet) has sometime some value who are not numbers (aka NaN, not a Number). Like x/0 is a Nan. So u should check how you're calculating ur scroll position. Show this section of code if u still have problems